# Firebase database downloads quota has been exceeded

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an android app with ~1500-3000 daily active users. In each time the app loads, I fetch the entire firebase database to make sure everything is on sync (i use [Firebase's offline capabilities](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities)). The entire database size is around 96kb (not huge at all).

I use the Flame plan, which offers 20GB of bandwidth. Since this month has been started, I've exceeded this quota by a huge amount of 300GB (!!!).

I probably should change the way I fetch the database at app load, but I am more worried about how this situation came to be. Any idea? I think this a bit odd for this simple app.

Also, how Firebase's app suspension works? Will the app be turned off for the next month?

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:**

The following is the code for fetching the desired data:

```
List<QuestionItem> questionsItemList = new ArrayList<>();
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("quests").orderByKey().addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            QuestionObject questionObject = snapshot.getValue(QuestionObject.class);
            questionsItemList.add(new QuestionItem(questionObject));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        // ...
    }
});
```

`QuestionObject` is just a plain object to be filled by Firebase. The `QuestionItem` constructor takes a `QuestionObject` and extract its properties.

Since then, I use `questionsItemList` to get a single document when I need it.

Comment: Maybe you could include some code to show exactly how you are fetching data.

Comment: *firebaser here* Without seeing the [minimal code that downloads more data](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) than you'd expect, it will be hard to help on Stack Overflow and you should probably [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting. You can also use [Firebase's recently introduced database profiling tool](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/profiling-your-realtime-database.html) to investigate yourself.

Comment: Well depending on the type of app, it could be that users are opening the app on average 35 times a day and then it would total up to 300GB. It's not to unrealistic that users open it 35 times a day, depending on the type of app

Comment: Added the code above.
I've ran the database profiler, which captured 54 operations. Looking at the Downloaded Bytes section, a total of 1.1MB were downloaded by 25 operations. Is it normal?

Comment: Could you add some more context where/how is that code called?

Answer (score 0):

I think I got the problem...

At app load I fetch some data, then store what I need in an `ArrayList`. When I need to get one of the document, I'll query it from the database instead of just get it from the `ArrayList`...

This may be the reason for the wasted bandwidth. I'll push an update soon, hopefully it'll fix the issue.